# How to show a form "smoothly" for second time in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, form-control

I have a form that should be shown by clicking on a button in main form and I want when users close the second form, main form be shown again on center of the screen. I used below codes to do this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide(); //Hides the main form .
    form2.ShowDialog(); //Shows the second form .
    this.Show(); // Re-shows the main form after closing the second form ( just in the taskbar , not on the screen ) .
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; // I write this code because I want to show the main form on the screen , not just in the taskbar .
}
```

these commands do what I want , but the problem is that after closing the second form , the main form be shown with a small jump, like a blink! (It's not continuous , it's just at the first.) What I want is do this smoothly, without any blink at the first. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a couple of guesses. Try inserting an Application.DoEvents before this.show(). Second, place the this.StartPosition before this.show().

Comment: @rontornambe I tried the second suggestion before and I've just tried the first one , but both of them do same . Anyway , Thank you .

Comment: Are these forms within an MDI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the opacity smoothly (main form must have the `AllowTransparency` property to `true`). This is very basic way to do it synchronously (blocking the main thread) but as it will last very little time this should be ok; no need for Application.DoEvents():

```
double opacity = 0.00;
while (opacity < 1)
{
    Opacity = opacity; // update main form opacity - transparency
    opacity += 0.04; // this can be changed
}
Opacity = 1.00 // make sure Opacity is 100% at the end
```

--- EDIT

Note you can do the same to hide the other form: just set initial opacity to 1.00 instead of 0.00 and then decrement ( -= ) instead of incrementing in the loop:

```
form2.Opacity -= opacity
```

Comment: Add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int value);` in loop if you want to get fancy